# R: I did cluster analysis - how do I append group classification to my original data?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

Supposer I've 4 varaibles (x, y, z, r) & 10 obs. I run the cluster analysis in R & get 2 clusters which are appropriate. Now I want to put these clusters in corresponds to the data. So the table will look as the following:

```
Respondent x,y,z,r cluster
1
2
3
.
.
10
```

Can anybody please tell me the code for getting this table. 
The code I used for cluster analysis is the following:

```
##Scaling
cluster1=scale(cluster)
###Hierarchial Cluster
cluster1=dist(cluster,method="euclidean")
summary(cluster1)
cluster2=hclust(cluster1,method="ward")
plot(cluster2)
```

Thanks
A

Comment: Some example data would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using your data, assuming the object cluster contains your original variables x, y , z and r in columns:

```
groups = cutree(cluster2, 2)
result = cbind(cluster, groups)
```